# Slitherlink #1 - Very Simple

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, slitherlink

This is a simple slitherlink, which is very easy.

[image: Slitherink]

The rules are as follows **(suggested by @bobble and @PuzzlingFerret)**:

1. There can be multiple loops.
2. The final solution should be a shape.

**Congrats to @fljx for solving it**

It was a

> : )

Comment: What are the rules of this slitherlink variant? Standard rules would make this puzzle impossible (multiple loops).

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: You can [edit] them in though.

Comment: Thank you @bobble and for Puzzling Ferret suggesting me to add the rules.

Sorry to everyone for messed up rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be a standard slitherlink puzzle, as it contains "4" clues, and requires multiple loops to complete.

The expected answer is probably:

> [image: Expected slitherlink solution]

But this isn't the only valid solution. There are several others, such as:

> [image: Alternate slitherlink solution]

Comment: Thank you for bringing that to my attention!