# Two Day Slitherlink

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, slitherlink

I recently learned what a Slitherlink puzzle is; from [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/115068/slitherlink-1-very-simple), so I tried my hand at making one! This is a normal 7x7 slitherlink, but with the added restriction that the loop must form the number 2 in celebration of two day! (I know I'm a bit late) A "two" should consist of two somewhat horizontal lines for the top and bottom and a transverse diagonal line that connects the other two lines.

A smaller example of this could be (for the letter C):

 https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dpYN.png

 https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YEtp.png

I've never made a puzzle like this before, so feedback would be appreciated. :D

> [image]

Comment: Please give a rigorous definition of "form the number 2". Grid-deductions depend on clear, unambiguous rules.

Comment: @bobble I've edited in a (hopefully rigorous) definition of "form the number 2". Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: It still seems unclear to me how this might be achieved. Perhaps you could give some examples on a smaller puzzle of the same style?

Comment: I'm going to sound like a broken record, but please give a rigorous definition of "somewhat horizontal line". Also, what slope is the diagonal line?

Comment: @bobble The 7x7 grid is not very big, and giving away details such as the slope of the diagonal would give the puzzle away. There should only be at most a couple of solutions that would resemble a 2, which would probably vary by one or two lines. I realize that "form the number 2" is very ambiguous but the example should help. I can delete my question if you want, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the problem

> is rather poorly constrained, I'm just going to throw 1 valid solution here...
>  [image: Image of a potential slitherlink solution]
>  Steps to attain this solution include:
>  (a) Making assumptions about the directionality of the 3s,
>  (b) attempting to minimize width for whatever goes from the bottom row to the top row, and
>  (c) assuming a "prettier" solution from the options for the top left corner

Comment: Nice job! I realize that my question should have been clearer and had more concise restrictions. Thanks for the feedback! +1